# Unable to access website added in hosts file in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, hosts, hosts-file

I have added a hostname in the /etc/hosts/ file in Mac OSX,when i try to run the URL with the hostname in the browser i couldn't able to access it , but when i try to access it with IPAddress I could able to access it.

Observations:
1)I can able to ping both IPAddress and hostname added to /etc/hosts file
2)I can able to access the URL with IPAddress but not with hostname
3)I tried flushing the dns Cache with following command

> dscacheutil -flushcache

4)I can able to access URL with hostname in windows machine.

So I appreciate any suggestions about what might have gone wrong....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Restart the browser?  Perhaps it keeps its own DNS cache.

Comment: What did you add to `/etc/hosts` and what sort of error do you get from the browser? Which browser, Safari? What does the URL look like?

Comment: Hi Thanks for you response,I got the problem resolved,it is the problem with our internal network proxy,i disabled the proxy